# How to effectively manage many different instances of the same app?

Tags: docker, architecture, software-design, multiple-instances, system-design

I want to build an application that would handle CRM, client database, time tracking etc.
The app would be sold to about 100 clients. The thing is that every one of clients will have slightly different needs i.e. they want to integrate app with their own accounting software or have added functionality only for them and in their instance, they want only those modules, that they are using.

I'll need to manage 100 different instances of the same app, so I want it to be easy. For example if I'd fix a bug for one instance I want it to be easy to propagate this bugfix to all other instances and if I create a module for one client I want to easily add it to another client's instance if he would want to.

What is the best way to do this in this situation?

I would be really thankful if someone would point me to the right direction ;)

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is handled by making things data-driven.  Everybody gets the same code, but with different [feature-flags](https://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html) which enable/disable various bits of the application.

Feature flags can be driven in a database, config files, environment variables, etc depending on your needs.